# ASP.Net Membership handling multiple registrations daily

Tags: asp.net, membership

Are there any known issues/limitations with using the asp.net membership db with respect to handling several registrations daily? My scenario is for an event booking system that captures and stores the users details (Name, number, e-mail, etc...) along with the event details. It is expected that about 100 new/returning users will use the system each day.

My guess is that it should not be an issue. Just looking for confirmation.

thanks
SD

Comment: thanks for the responses. I think I'm now leaning towards using the membership db for the "user management" and storing the event entities/reference tables etc... in another db.

thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious reason it shouldn't handle 100 user registration a day.

Answer (score 1):

That's only around 36,000 users/transactions a year.

I'm assuming you will have a table to store the event details related on the user ID (which is a GUID in the asp.net membership default provider).

That rate of growth should be easily handled by SQL Server. You will just need to index your table correctly. Honestly you won't notice a problem at this rate for several years WITHOUT indexing...

Good luck with your venture.

Answer (score 1):

Unless all 100 users need to complete their registrations within the same one or two seconds, or unless your hardware or back-end setup is really terrible, you will be fine.

The limitation of the Membership system that you're likely to encounter first is related to the total number of registered users. I would consider a custom system for anything beyond roughly 100,000 users (assuming reasonable hardware).